# Creating a Variable of Present Date Minus a Past Timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

In the code below, "created" is a field in a MySQL table.  This field is of the type "timestamp" and the default is set to "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" of whenever a given row is created.

In the query below, I would like to create a new variable that equals the present date minus the timestamp of "created", rounded off to units of days.  I would like the present date to be whenever the query is run.

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT 
    l.loginid, 
    l.username, 
    l.created,
    ...
```

Comment: Do you mean calendar days, or 24 hour periods? If I create the record at 23:58 and run the query 10 minutes later, should it show zero or one day?

Comment: Hmm... good question.  I guess 24 hours periods would be better than calendar days.  But it would be interesting to see how to do both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

```
DATEDIFF(NOW(), l.created)
```

If you want 24-hour periods instead, you can use...

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, NOW(), l.created)
```

...and then divide by 24 and round or floor as you choose.